# Insert Byte Data to Sqlite without b' preceeding

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, byte

I'm trying to insert into my sqlite3 database, an encrypted username, but its including `b'` proceeding the actual value.

This is causing issues on my application.

My code looks like:

```
hashed_username = enc(prompt_account_username, salt)
print('\n\nusername: {}\n\n'.format(hashed_username))
```

This prints:

```
username:

b'sc\x00\x02\x16\x88\x04\xa2\x9d\xb9!\xe0\x9e-5\xb3\x8a\xd8r\xbc\x83\x01\r\x98\xb1\xe3\xb2i=\x16\xc8Y\xbe\xdd\x0f\x8e\x8c\xa2\xb0\xd0R\xf7gx2\x1d\xfb\xfeX\xda\xb9Y\xd6Ls\x88\xaa<\x9c\x12\xf3\xbeq\r\x8d\xcb\xc0\x8adF\x1dl\xc5\xde'
```

This is then inserting this full byte value, including the `b'`

When I run:

```
conn.execute("""
            INSERT INTO my_acct
            (acct_username)
            VALUES (?) """, (v[0], )
            )
```

How can I get it to insert, just the value, without the `b'`, with a value like:

```
sc\x00\x02\x16\x88\x04\xa2\x9d\xb9!\xe0\x9e-5\xb3\x8a\xd8r\xbc\x83\x01\r\x98\xb1\xe3\xb2i=\x16\xc8Y\xbe\xdd\x0f\x8e\x8c\xa2\xb0\xd0R\xf7gx2\x1d\xfb\xfeX\xda\xb9Y\xd6Ls\x88\xaa<\x9c\x12\xf3\xbeq\r\x8d\xcb\xc0\x8adF\x1dl\xc5\xde
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `memoryview` to insert binary data into sqlite, like this:

```
conn.execute("""
        INSERT INTO my_acct
        (acct_username)
        VALUES (?) """, (memoryview(v[0]), )
        )
```

**NOTE**: in **python 2** one would use the `buffer` builtin in this case. `buffer` is not available anymore in **python 3** and has been replaced by `memoryview`.

Comment: When I try this:
inserting: name 'buffer' is not defined. SQL Looks like: conn.execute("""INSERT INTO my_acct (acct_username) VALUES(?)""", (buffer(v[0]),))  . What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `buffer` is a python 2 builtin. I guess you are using python 3 so in this case you can replace it with `memoryview`. Im updating my answer

Comment: No need to thank me! We both learnt in the process, as I didn't know `buffer` had been removed and replaced by `memoryview` in python3 ;-)

Comment: @arainone Do you know a way I can retrieve that same binary using SELECT and WHERE?